# Does my question (currently on Programmers.se) fit the boundaries of SO?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

My question is this: Creating a bare bone web-browser: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/242881/creating-a-bare-bone-web-browser-after-the-html-parser-javascript-parser-etc

I got a couple of useful comments which gave me some idea but I still haven't got a concrete answer to my question. I want to start a bounty on it but do not have enough reputation for it. I do have enough reps on SO though. Does my question fit the boundaries of SO?

If it doesn't get any more comments or answers, I would like to have it moved to SO.

Moderators: I don't want the question to be moved now. I will ask for this favor if I don't get any answers on Programmers.se and my question fits the boundaries of SO.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Since you edited your question to point to a link instead of the text you posed in your question, I'll expand my answer.

It is both 'too broad', and 'off topic tool recommendation'.

Here's why:

> 18. The browser renders the page on the screen according to the DOM tree and the style information for each node
>
> I need help with step 18. How do I do that?

That's too broad.

Then your comment:

> I want to use a layout renderer but I want it to only do the work from the DOM tree that I create. I wouldn't want it to handle anything else. Can you suggest me something.

That's the "Off topic because you're asking for a tool recommendation" part.

Anyway you slice it, you need to do more research before coming to Stack Overflow. Perhaps hundreds (if not thousands) of hours of research, given the topic you're attacking.  I wish you well.

---

No. This question is too broad.

Do some more research; narrow it down. Read the Mozilla Firefox source code (or Chromium).  Come to us when you have a specific issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.  Step #3 of building a browser isn't answerable in a few paragraphs.

In general, Stack Overflow isn't a replacement for research. Stack Overflow is the place to come when your research and problem has been narrowed down to something that's distillable, answerable, and useful to others in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, I was told on meta.se to delete the question from there and ask it here. I would just like to point out that in my question in programmers.se, I have made few additions (before asking this question on meta.SO). I don't need help with step 3 anymore. There is a **step 18** inside quoted text in my question. I just want to know if a layout renderer like gecko or webkit do that particular work or the whole work of fetching everything, creating dom trees, etc.

Comment: And I thought I could do this within 100 hours (or atmost 150). I will have to think up my approach again. Anyway, thank you for the answer.